# Update ids from 2 different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables :

- `t1` : id, m_id, date
- `t2` : p_id, p_code
- `t3` : p_id, p_code, event_id

How do I update the ids in `t1`?

```
where id in (select p_id from t2 inner join t3 on t2.p_code = t3.p_code)
```

Comment: You need to have some context to connect the resulting p_id values from your query to records in t1.

Comment: select id from t1 where id in (select p_id from t2 inner join t3 on t2.p_code = t3.p_code).                                                                                                           This is how the ids are connected with other two tables t2 nd t3

Comment: To what are you going to update the ids in t1? Do you mean "ids" as "m_id"?

Comment: i want to update ids in t1 to p_ids from t2 based on the condition mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET id = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.p_id
            FROM t2 INNER JOIN t3
            WHERE t2.p_code = t3.p_code)
WHERE <conditon> -- choose rows to update
```